# Multiple instances of jQuery autocomplete combobox on one page

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox

I would like to have **multiple JQuery autocomplete comboboxes** on one html page. (How) is this possibe?

I discovered the id for the combobox matters. In the example below the only combobox shown with JQuery is the first one.
I prefer not to duplicate (too many of) the JQuery script code (I've put this code in a .js-file and generate the comboboxes in a .php-file)

I have this (this is just the code from the demo example at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

```
<select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
</select>
<select id="combobox2">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
</select>

(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
        _create: function() {
            var self = this,
                select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
            var input = this.input = $( "<input>" )
                .insertAfter( select )
                .val( value )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                        response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                            var text = $( this ).text();
                            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }) );
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                    },
                    change: function( event, ui ) {
                        if ( !ui.item ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                valid = false;
                            select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                    this.selected = valid = true;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            if ( !valid ) {
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $( this ).val( "" );
                                select.val( "" );
                                input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

            input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };              
            
            this.button = $( "<button type='button' class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-icon-only ui-corner-right ui-button-icon ui-state-hover'><span class='ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s'></span><span class='ui-button-text'>&nbsp;</span></button>" )
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                .attr( "role", "button" )
                .attr( "aria-disabled", "false" )
                .insertAfter( input )
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .click(function() {
                    // close if already visible
                    if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                        input.autocomplete( "close" );
                        return;
                    }

                    // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                    $( this ).blur();

                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                    input.focus();
                });
        },

        destroy: function() {
            this.input.remove();
            this.button.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
        }
    });
})( jQuery );

$(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
        $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Jan

Answer (score 6):

Assuming all you need is to select the target element, you just need to select by class or multiple IDs like this:

```
$('.combobox').combobox(); // would need to add this shared class to markup

// OR
$('#combobox, #combobox2').combobox(); // should work with existing markup
```

I'm more for using classes so that you don't always have to manually add more IDs as you grow.

Note that the toggle button they include is just as a demo to show the underlying 'real' combobox. I don't think you need to bind a toggle.

[Fiddles found in comments:]

http://jsfiddle.net/6wMz9/ (using ID)

http://jsfiddle.net/6wMz9/1/ (4 comboboxes, using class)

Comment: Hi Greg
Thanks for your quick reply!
I tried both options, but in both cases only the first combobox is turned into a jquery widget...
I already deleted the toggle button, because I indeed do not need it...

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6wMz9/ (note the styles are missing and the button is empty.. that's just because the jQuery UI CSS isn't present. But you can tell that it worked)

Comment: With class instead of ID (note addition to HTML markup is necessary. They all get `class="combobox"`) http://jsfiddle.net/6wMz9/1/

Comment: Hi Greg. I found the solution. The scripts I downloaded from JQuery with the customized download (I donwloaded only autocomplete and dependencies) were not good. I use the same scripts as in your example now and now it works. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: No problem! You're a new user so you probably didn't know this, but there's a checkmark next to the answer you can click on to show that this answer worked for you. ;-) I get a few points and people see that you accept answers (which helps you later on as well)

Answer (score 4):

user1264532

I wanted to do the same, i have multiple combobox instances, but the ID was the matter, so what I did was to add the same ID to the span created by the [autocomplete.combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) example. The only change is in the constructor:

```
        _create: function () {
        console.log(this);
            this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                .addClass("custom-combobox")
                .insertAfter(this.element)
                .attr('id', this.element[0].id+'_combobox');
            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
        },
```

And just call it this way

```
    $("#combobox1").combobox();
    $("#combobox2").combobox();
```

I did this cuz I need to catch the **change** event on each combobox and in the other answers I couldn't achieve that. Hope this helps.

here is a jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/WyQKE/2/) cheers!